# Logic proving that $A$ is a subset of $B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

Let $A = \{x \in \mathbb{Z} \mid x \equiv 5 \pmod{15}\}$ and $B = \{ x \in \mathbb{Z} \mid x \equiv 2 \pmod{3}\}.$

Give an outline of a proof that $A \subseteq B,$ being as detailed as possible. Then prove the statement.

To create a proof of this would I be correct in starting off by:

Let $A = \{ x \in \mathbb{Z} \mid x \equiv 5 \pmod{15}\},$ and let $B = \{x \in \mathbb{Z} \mid x \equiv 2 \pmod{3}\}.$

Let $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ be arbitrary,

I am a bit stuck on where to go from here though in this outline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Outline*: Note that you want to prove that given two subsets $A$ and $B$ we have that $A \subseteq B.$ By definition, this means that, given an object $x$
>
> $$x \in A \implies x \in B.$$
>
> So this is our way: we pick an element from $A$ and then we show that it have to belong to $B$ as well.

*Proof*: Let $x \in A.$ By definition of $A,$ we know that

$$x \equiv 5 \pmod{15}.$$

This means that

$$x = 15k + 5 \quad \text{for some } k \in \mathbb{Z}.$$

But we also have that

$$\begin{align}
x & = 15k + 5\\
& = 3(5k) + 3 + 2\\
& = 3(5k + 1) + 2
\end{align}$$

Since $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $5k + 1 \in \mathbb{Z}.$ Then we conclude that $x \equiv 2 \pmod{3}.$ Hence $x \in B.$ Since $x \in A \implies x \in B$ we have that $A \subseteq B.$ $\square$